# Certain HTML entity codes not being evaluated

Tags: html, django, unicode, character-encoding

I have a view passing on information from a database:

```
def serve_article(request, id):
    served_article = Article.objects.get(pk=id)

    # Strips out new line and tab characters
    article_snippet = served_article.full_text.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')

    # Gets first 300 word characters
    article_snippet = re.match(r'(.{,300})\W', article_snippet).group(1)

    return render(request, 'article.html', {'served_article':served_article,
                                            'article_snippet':article_snippet})
```

`article_snippet`, a unicode string by the time it is rendered, contains many HTML entity codes (for example: `&#8217;` maps to ’ and `&copy;` maps to © when rendered)

However, `{{ article_snippet }}` in the template does not evaluate these symbols, leaving them blank as if they were wrapped inside a `<code>` tag (they aren't).

I've got `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top, and other symbols on the page that are evaluating fine, so clearly these symbols are being escaped somehow. Why is this behavior happening, and how do I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable auto-escaping for an individual variable, use the `safe` filter:

```
This will be escaped: {{ data }}
This will not be escaped: {{ data|safe }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Ensure that your variable does not contain dangerous HTML provided by user (`<script>` tags etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Riateche suggested using the safe filter which will serve you 90% of the time, other times (need to format HTML into a message - using the django messging framework) you need to be able to do it by hand.

to manually make the string safe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def serve_article(request, id):
    served_article = Article.objects.get(pk=id)

    # Strips out new line and tab characters
    article_snippet = served_article.full_text.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')

    # Gets first 300 word characters
    article_snippet = re.match(r'(.{,300})\W', article_snippet).group(1)

    # MARK THIS VALUE AS SAFE IN YOUR VIEW
    article_snippet = mark_safe(article_snippet)

    return render(request, 'article.html', {'served_article':served_article,
                                        'article_snippet':article_snippet})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in Django V1.9 if you stack the safe template tag after other template tags, it does not work so make sure safe is directly after the context variable!

**.py CODE**

```
context['variable'] = "&trade;"
```

**HTML**

*THE FOLLOWING WORKS*

```
{{ variable|safe|capfirst|linebreaksbr }} -> displays: TM
```

*THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK*

```
{{ variable|capfirst|linebreaksbr|safe }} -> displays: &trade;
```

Answer (score 0):

The common mistake is giving a wrong script src...
Copy and paste the correct link ..
ie, go to www.angular js org...
Click on download angular js..
Copy the CDN link..
Paste it in front of script src..
So this will give you the correct evaluated answer in html ..